# Is it possible to get Platinium in closed-server games with online multiplayer trophies?

Tags: achievements, ps4, ps3, psn

Is it possible to achieve platinum trophy in some old games, which have dead multiplayer, with multiplayer trophies listed?

Do situations like that have any exceptions, which allow completing the game with platinum, but with not completed multiplayer trophies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. If their server was closed, and the multiplayer is dead, it's no longer possible to achieve those trophies. It happened a lot with old PS3 games.

For reference:

- [list of games with unobtainable platinum for generic reasons](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/63108-list-of-games-with-an-unobtainable-platinum100/)
- [list of games with unobtainable platinum due to server-shutdowns](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/309260-server-shutdowns-and-unobtainable-trophies/)

Comment: You're right. In some games like Far Cry 3/4, Red Dead Redemption, GTA IV, and more platinum are impossible to reach. I was thinking that maybe Sony made these multiplayer trophies as optional to allows mastering these games in current times too, but seems that nothing like that happened and will happen (probably)

Comment: @TravelerVihaan I feel you because I always wondered the same, but it seems unlikely that Sony may change that, also because trophies don't affect the playability of the game, and fixing all those trophies lists is a long work without any benefict. I don't like this kind of trophy, and it's just not fair requiring them for platinum.

Comment: Nier Automata has a curious feature that lets you "buy" missing trophies with in-game currency in the late game, that could be a solution...

Comment: As a mainly single-player, I agree with you. When I had seen multiplayer trophies on the achievements list of some games, I was losing so much motivation to mastering the game. It was not worth it for me, to spend millions of hours in battles with people, which are unbelievable better than me in online gameplay.

Comment: I really enjoy collecting trophies, but I would never pay real money for that. Achieving them is the main fun for me.

Comment: I agree. What I meant with "buy missing trophies" is not spending real money btw, just using the resources/coins/units collected while playing.