# How to find out if game servers are still active or if a game is still being played online by people?

Tags: game-server

I like to experience many games online but as they are old, when you play the game you find out that the servers are empty.

For example, *Gears of War 4* servers are totally empty but a game like *PUBG: Battlegrounds* is still highly active after many years.

How can I find out that a game is still being played online by enough amount of people?

Comment: Okay, now my age is showing. When you said the games were old, I mentally jumped to SOCOM 2 on PS2 then I read GoW4 lol 

Comment: Do you mean other than by logging in and checking?

Comment: Related, in this question was asked if it's still possible to get Platinum trophy of games with dead multiplayer, the [accepted answer provides a list of games with closed servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/389899/87579).

Answer (score 4):

if a game is part of a franchise (like gears), only the most recent entry will likely be most populated. When it's standalone entry, like PUBG, it will usually remain populated until the game itself dies.

There are a few exceptions here, but this is a pretty good rule of thumb.

Notable exceptions would be Battlefield, as 3 and 4 are still very much populated, probably even more than the recent entries in the franchise. Because Battlefield covers different time periods, people play the time period they enjoy most. Another exception would be Halo, but this is a different exception. All of the old games are compiled into the Master Chief Collection. Even though these are all old games (the original being 20), it is still very active and you can find servers in any game or mode.

Comment: "if a game is part of a franchise (like gears), only the most recent entry will likely be most populated." Unless it's an RTS from the late 90s.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the game on sites like steamcharts.com. It usually shows how many people are currently playing a game. Even if you're not playing on PC, it will still give you an idea if a game is still active or not.

Comment: But it doesn't say anything about the server population of games, which is what the OP is asking for.